# Refresh data with RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, observable, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm using Retrofit with RxJava2 to obtain some data from a Rest API. I want to use a `SwipeRefreshLayout` to update the view and I'm using a `ViewModel` to handle the API call, so I want to implement a method in there to refresh the data programmatically.

I want to obtain something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276564/6787552 but instead of having a periodic trigger, I want to do that programmatically when the user pull to refresh.

That's the `ViewModel`:

```java
public class DashboardViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public final Single<Dashboard> dashboard;

    public DashboardViewModel() {
        dashboard = Api.getDashboard();
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh() {
        // Refresh data 
    }
}
```

And in the `DashboardFragment`:

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        viewModel.dashboard
                 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .subscribe(dashboard -> {
                     binding.setDashboard(dashboard);
                     binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                 });

        binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> viewModel.refresh());
        ...
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

That's what I ended up doing:

```java
public class DashboardViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final BehaviorSubject<Dashboard> dashboard;

    public DashboardViewModel() {
        dashboard = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Api.getDashboard());
    }

    public void refresh() {
        // I use a Object because null values are not supported
        dashboard.onNext(Api.getDashboard());
    }

    public Observable<Dashboard> getDashboard(){
        return dashboard;
    }
}
```

And then in the `DashboardFragment` just subscribe to `viewModel.getDashbaord()`

Comment: Call this, ```Api.getDashboard();```

Comment: Where? And this would create a new `Single` I guess, so I'd have to resubscribe in the fragment.

Comment: are you sure that you need a single? if you need to update the ui every time you get a new dashbord I expect it to be an observable.

Comment: No, you're right. I put a Single just as an example because the api call return a  Single.

Comment: Aftre your edit with the implementation, I think you can probably do something a bit cleaner - unless there's a reason to have the map from object to dashboard:


`public class DashboardViewModel extends ViewModel {

 
    private final BehaviorSubject<Dashboard> dashboard;

    public DashboardViewModel() {
        dashboard = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Api.getDashboard());
    }

    public void refresh() {
        dashboard.onNext(Api.getDashboard());
    }

    public Observable<Dashboard> getDashboard(){
        return dashboard;
    }
}`
(sorry it's all inline)

Comment: Yes that's better, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understood what you want to do but if I got the question right, you can do something like this:

- put a subject inside the model  (probably a BehaviorSubject?)
- expose it as an observable to the
  view and subscribe to it (instead of subscribing to the single)
- in the model, when you
  receive a new call to `refresh()` from the ui, do something like
  `subject.onNext(Api.getDashboard())`

in this way, each call to refresh will cause the emission of a new dashboard, and that will be properly bound by the subscription in the view.